# Initialization difference with or without curly braces in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

We can initialize the variable in two ways in C++

**One:**

```
int abc = 7;
```

**Two:**

```
int abc {7};
```

What is the difference between these two methods? Does the compiler treat them differently, or is there a difference in the way the code is executed?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: For `int` specifically, the only difference is that `{}` prohibits narrowing conversion, e.g. from a literal that's too large to fit into an `int`. For class types, it might get complicated depending on how detailed you want to know the differences.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

#### Short version

Initialization via `{..}` is list-initialization, which prohibits narrowing conversions. For example, if `LLONG_MAX` is the maximum value of an `long long int`, and your `int` cannot represent that:

```
int x = LLONG_MAX;  // probably accepted with a warning
int x {LLONG_MAX};  // error
```

Similarly:

```
long long y = /*something*/;

int x = y;  // accepted, maybe with a warning
int x {y};  // error
```

---

#### Long version

An initialization of the form

```
T x = a;
```

is *copy-initialization*; an initialization of either form

```
T x(a);
T x{a};
```

is *direct-initialization*, [dcl.init]/15-16.

[dcl.init]/14 then says:

> The form of initialization (using parentheses or `=`) is generally insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity being initialized has a class type; see below.

So for non-class types, the *form* of the initialization doesn't matter. However, there's a difference between these two direct-initializations:

```
T x(a);  // 1
T x{a};  // 2
```

and similarly, between these two copy-initializations:

```
T x = a;    // 1
T x = {a};  // 2
```

Namely, the ones with `{..}` use list-initialization. The `{..}` is called a *braced-init-list*.

So, when you compare `T x = a;` to `T x {a};`, there are *two* differences: copy- vs. direct-initialization, and "non-list-" vs. list-initialization. As already mentioned by others and in the quote above, for non-class types `T`, there's no difference between copy- and direct-init. However, there's a difference between list-init and no list-init. That is, we could as well compare

```
int x (a);
int x {a};
```

List-initialization in this case prohibits narrowing conversions. Narrowing conversions are defined in [dcl.init.list]/7 as:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> - from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
> - from `long double` to `double` or `float`, or from `double` to `float`, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented
>     (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source
>     is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will
>     produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the
>     values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral
>     promotions will fit into the target type.

Comment: What about this kind of initialization using both parens and braces: `std::random_device{}()` ?

Comment: @moooeeeep This is not a separate kind of initialization. It constructs an temporary of type `std::random_device` by using the expression `std::random_device{}`, and then calls that object's overloaded `operator()`, just like `std::random_device rd; rd()` would. The `random_device` has an `operator()` which invokes the RNG and returns a (pseudo)random number, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/operator()

Comment: Nice, thanks! Now that you explained it, it seems obvious.

Comment: I tried to initialize with int b1{2147483648}; . But I do not get error, instead get only the warning "warning: narrowing conversion of '2147483648ll' from 'long long int' to 'int' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]|. Why it is so?

Comment: @Rajesh Which compiler and version? Apparently, this was a warning only up until gcc 5. See also: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783

Comment: @dyp: GCC version is -  gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2. I used default MinGW compiler came as part of codeBlocks 16.01. So I guess if I go for latest GCC, I can solve this problem. But there are two versions. 5.5 has this fix. But what about 7.2? This should be latest version I guess. But does this have this fix as well?

Comment: Tried with tdm64-gcc-5.1.0-2. 
I get error for int b1{2147483648}; . 
But I do get only warning instead of error for 
long long k=12;
int b2{k};

Comment: @Rajesh From the C++ Standard's point of view, both a warning and an error are acceptable messages. What's important is that the compiler emits some form of message and rejects narrowing conversions in SFINAE-scenarios like https://wandbox.org/permlink/5fdHJ1yLrCAXwg82 You can configure gcc via -Werror=narrowing, e.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/LCGsa2V9kPrXRqt4

Answer (score 4):

While for `int` the existing replies are complete, I *painfully* found out, that in some cases, there are other differences between the `()` and `{}` initializations.

The keyword is that `{}` is an initializer list.

One such cases is, the `std::string` initialization with `count` copies of a `char`:

```
std::string stars(5, '*')
```

will initialize `stars` as `*****`, but

```
std::string stars{5, '*'}
```

will be read as `std::string stars(char(5), '*')` and initialize star as `*` (preceded by an hidden character).

Answer (score 1):

The first is the copy initialization, while the second is list initialization.

But, usually copy initialization is less used. Because, if you're doing it by passing objects of user defined types, it just causes bitcopy & hence may not produce intended results if the user defined class uses pointers.

Comment: Not if they have copy constructors, surely?  I'm way beyond confused now.

Comment: @RichieHH If user defined type has pointers, then one should prefer to write copy constructor along with constructor & destructor (Rule of 3). But, if there's no copy constructor, then it will cause 'shallow copy' & may cause dangling pointers.

Comment: Exactly.  User defined types using pointers should have copy and initialise constructors. Maybe edit your reply. Thanks for getting back.