# Difference between new int () and new int { } in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator

I know the difference between `new int()` and `new int(10)`. In first case 0 is assigned and in second case 10 is assigned to newly created int. But what is the between `new int {}`. We use {} for array initialization like `new a[]{4,5,6}`. But for single variable what is the meaning of using braces while initializing?

```
/* Combined usage and initialized to 0*/
    int *ptr2 = new int();
    cout<<"*ptr2 = "<<*ptr2<<endl;

    /* Allocated memory can be initialized to specific value */
    int*ptr3 = new int(5);
    cout<<"*ptr3 = "<<*ptr3<<endl;

    int* ptr5 = new int{500};
    cout<<"*ptr5 = "<<*ptr5<<endl;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialization difference with or without Curly braces in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150067/initialization-difference-with-or-without-curly-braces-in-c11)

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is this:

```
*ptr2 =  0 

*ptr3 =  5 

*ptr5 =  500
```

No difference in your situation.

But in general :

```
( expression-list )     (1)     
= expression            (2)     
{ initializer-list }    (3)
```

> 1) comma-separated list of arbitrary expressions and braced-init-lists
>   in parentheses
>
> 2) the equals sign followed by an expression
>
> 3) braced-init-list: possibly empty, comma-separated list of
>   expressions and other braced-init-lists

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Answer (score 1):

In the particular case of `int` (or any integral type e.g. `long`) there is no difference between `new int(10)` and `new int{10}`.

Read more about [variable initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).